# U.S. Supreme Court record items

Tags: data-request, government

Is there source of U.S. Supreme Court record items (merit and amicus briefs, appendices, etc.) from 1942?

I'm interested in a general answer, but in particular, I'm interested in the record from *Wickard v. Filburn*, 317 U.S. 111 (1942).

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is no complete online archive of historic US Supreme Court documents.

There are links to recent indices of online material from http://www.supremecourt.gov/default.aspx, and the court actually redirects seekers of online merits briefs to the [American Bar Association's "Preview" publication](http://www.americanbar.org/publications/preview_home/alphabetical.html) A direct index of cases is available for 2012-13 and 2013-14; for earlier material, PDFs of *Preview* can be downloaded, but only back to the 2007-08 session.

The FindLaw site has [online briefs dating to 1999](http://supreme.lp.findlaw.com/supreme_court/briefs/index.1999.html).

I don't have access to WestLaw, but the SCOTUS site suggests that it may have historic briefs. If so, I would not assume that they have them as far back as 1942.

Otherwise, I believe you'd have to visit a law library or use a commercial document retrieval service, which would send a person to the court to make copies of the relevant documents for you. [This page](http://www.supremecourt.gov/oral_arguments/briefsource.aspx) lists libraries which are repositories for printed briefs as well as listing services which can retrieve documents for you (for a fee).